# Python List Mutation RGB Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, rgb, mutation

Given list L below (RGB values), how do I mutate the list so that if the third value in each individual list (the B value) is not divisible by 2, then subtract one. Otherwise, leave it alone.

```py
L = [[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 256]], [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]]]
```

The code should return none, and the code should look like this after:

```py
L = [[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 256]], [[255, 255, 254], [255, 255, 254]]]
```

This is my current code; but it doesn't seem to work, as I need some help with the mutation part.

```py
def blue(L):
    for row in L:
      for rgb in row:
        if rgb[2] % 2 != 0:
          rgb[2] = rgb[2] - 1
```

All help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" means what exactly?

Comment: It does work, you just need to call your function `blue(L)`

Comment: I tried printing and returning blue(L) but it's printing None and returning None

Comment: The function modifies L inplace. If you additionally want a return you must append "return L" (outside of the loops).

Comment: Can you please update your question to include a code block representing what you'd like L to look like after you're done mutating it?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

**Your function changes `L` in place and does not `return` anything so get None if you print the function.**

Use this:

```
def blue(mylist):
    for row in mylist:
        for rgb in row:
            if rgb[2] % 2 != 0:
                rgb[2] = rgb[2] - 1
    return mylist

L = [[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 256]], [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]]]
mutated_L = blue(L)
print(mutated_L)
[[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 256]], [[255, 255, 254], [255, 255, 254]]]
```